# If element has class and another element is empty change class on another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html structure, this is a snippet there is lots more in the same structure.

```
<button id="showEmpty">Press</button>
<div class="children">
    <div class="package">
        <span class="name"></span>
        <span class="value"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="package array">
        <span class="name"></span>
        <span class="value"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="package">
        <span class="name"></span>
        <span class="value"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="package array">
        <div class="children">
            <div class="package array">
                <span class="name"></span>
                <span class="value"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="package">
                <span class="name"></span>
                <span class="value"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="package array">
                <div class="children">
                    <div class="package array">
                        <span class="name"></span>
                        <span class="value"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="package array">
                        <span class="name"></span>
                        <span class="value"></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="package">
                        <span class="name"></span>
                        <span class="value"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to find all of the div elements with the class 'array' and then the span elements with the class 'value' within those div that dont have any content.

Those that  apply I want to change the class of another span element within the div with the class 'name' to say 'empty'.

I have this code so far, but I'm not sure where to go next.

```
(function(){
    $('#showEmpty').click(function() {
        if ($('div.package').each().hasClass('array') && $('span.value').each().text().trim().length()) {
            $('span.value').removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
        else alert('no arrays found');
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT: I would also need to only do this where the array div's don't have children div's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One easy way is(assuming the empty `span` will be `<span></span>`, ie there is no blank content in it)

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#showEmpty').click(function () {        
        $('div.package.array').has('span.value:empty').find('span.name').removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
    });
});
```

Here we finds `div` with classes `package` and `array` which has an empty `span` with class `value`, then find the `span` with class `name` in those div and remove and add class

---

If the `span.value` can have blank values then you can use a filter

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#showEmpty').click(function () {
        $('div.package.array').filter(function () {
            return $('span.value', this).text().trim().length() > 0;
        }).find('span.name').removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly! Would it be possible to check if the first div doesn't contain a div with the class 'children' in the same statement

Comment: @Pedroson so if there is the children class then you don't have to run this

Comment: I would need to run that, as well as checking for the children class. The children class should be checked before the span is checked. Thanks

Comment: $('div.package.array')  [check if there is not a children class here]   .has('span.value:empty')...... I would need to check that there is not an element with the class children within the array div

Comment: Sorry, to be more clear I only want to carry out that function, where the array div doesn't contain a div with the class 'children'.

Comment: @Pedroson then `$('div.package.array').has('span.value:empty').not(':has(.children)').`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84071/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-pedroson).

Comment: Thanks for helping, the fiddle you sent me worked perfectly.

Comment: @Pedroson glad it helped... the requirement was not that clear to me

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function:

```
$('.array').each(function(){
    if ($(this).children('span.value').text() === "")
    {
        $(this).children('span.name').addClass('empty').removeClass('name');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g53q3Lgz/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.package.array > span.value').each(function () {
        $('span.name').removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
$('#showEmpty').click(function () {
    $(".array > span.value:empty").siblings(".name").removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
});
```

[Here is the JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xquoqxLr/)

You can inspect-element to see the changes on button click.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#showEmpty').click(function() {
        $('div.package span.value').each(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length==0) {
              $(this).parent().find('span.name').removeClass('name').addClass('empty');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n2o55xve/

Hope it helps.